# Цены на сайте WordPress c WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Мне нужно сделать динамику цен на сайте следующим образом:

если стоимость товаров не более 1000 руб. то наценка 200%

если стоимость товаров не более 5000 руб. то наценка 100%

если стоимость товаров не более 15000 руб. то наценка 50%

если стоимость товаров не более 30000 руб. то наценка 20%

То есть я завожу новый товар, в поле цены вбиваю оптовую цену, цена проходит через фильтр, и отображается на сайте по заданным мною параметрам!

Пробовал добавить такой фильтр →

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cur_price', 10, 2);
global $woocommerce;
$product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); 
$xprice = $product->get_price_html();
function cur_price()
      {if($xprice <= 250){
    $curprice = $xprice *3;
} elseif ($xprice > 250 || $xprice <= 1000){
    $curprice = $xprice *2;
} elseif ($xprice > 1000 || $xprice <= 2500){
    $curprice = $xprice *1.5;
}
else {
    $curprice = $xprice *1.2;
}
return $curprice;
}
```

Всегда результат «0» но в корзине отображает обычную цену!

Что странно, потестировал с файлом `/single-product/price.php`
вместо `<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>`

вставил свою функцию, но вместо `$product->get_price_html();` вставил `$product->get_regular_price();` и все сработало (только на странице товара, соответственно)

Подскажите, это фильтр не так делаю, либо `get_price_html();` отображается не как не цифра, а текст в виде цифр или в чем проблема??

Comment: `get_price_html()` возвращает html-код цены. Какие уж тут цифры...

Comment: И что это у вас $xprice вычисляется вне функции, а используется внутри? Внутри она null, само собой. Понятно, что null * 1.2 = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо фильтровать не html-код цены, а саму цену. Вставьте такой фильтр:

```
function curr_price( $value, $_this ) {
    $value = intval( $value );
    if ( $value <= 250 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 3;
    } elseif ( $value > 250 && $value <= 1000 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 2;
    } elseif ( $value > 1000 && $value <= 2500 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 1.5;
    } else {
        $curr_price = $value * 1.2;
    }

    return $curr_price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'curr_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: KAGG Design , спасибо, теперь я понял где я валянок, и ухожу в литературу по РНР, все сработало как надо!

Comment: это несущественно. я в формулу вашу не вдавался. мне надо было показать, каким хуком и как можно обновить цену. А уж как ее считать - дело десятое

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: Php изучать, конечно, полезно. Но для решения данной задачи ещё нужны знания WordPress и WooCommerce. Так что добавьте их в свой список)

Answer (score 0):

Только я вместо лог. оператора " || " или - подставил оператор  и '' && '',   с оператором "или" доходило только до первого "elseif" и дальше не считало, теперь моя формула выглядит так:

```
function curr_price( $value, $_this ) {
    $value = intval( $value );
    if ( $value <= 250 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 3;
    } elseif ( $value > 250 && $value <= 500 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 2;
    } elseif ( $value > 500 && $value <= 1000 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 1.8;
    } elseif ( $value > 1000 && $value <= 2500 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 1.5;
    } elseif ( $value > 2500 && $value <= 5000 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 1.3;
    } elseif ( $value > 5000 && $value <= 8000 ) {
        $curr_price = $value * 1.2;
    } else {
        $curr_price = $value * 1.1;
    }
    return $curr_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'curr_price', 10, 2 );
```

и по каждому пункту считает  корректно! 
Спасибо что направили меня, мои знания рнр очень скудны!